# Is using “Miss” here correct?

Tags: titles

In the English textbook for third-graders in Vietnam, there’s a segment that goes:
[image: hello]

My question is: is this a correct way to address your name as a teacher (as in Miss Hien) to your student?
Shouldn’t it just be “I am Hien.” instead?
Thank you for your input.

Comment: In Australia, primary students address teachers as *Mr/Ms/Miss/Mrs Surname* (where choice of title is up to each individual teacher).

Comment: Informally, we may refer to an instructor simply by their surname, but in all English speaking countries, when we address them formally, they will be Mr./Ms. or Miss or Mrs. depending on personal preference for female instructors.

Comment: @GArthurBrown -  While people might do that it’s not just informal, it’s disrespectful and certainly young children in primary school would never be encouraged to it.

Comment: @Jim, not sure what the issue is. Informal: "marked by the absence of formality or ceremony." Is this somehow unclear in my comment?

Comment: Is Hien her family name or her given name? (I'm assuming that that distinction exists in Vietnamese society). If it's her family name (the one shared with and inherited from a parent) then it would be disrespectful for children not to use a title; however if she wants them to use her given name the title would not be used. For instance I am "Mr Bold" to people who don't know me or people who are being respectful but to my family, friends and colleagues I am "Ben". Nobody calls me "Mr Ben".